# Attempts to load a powershell library failing

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I am attempting to run a powershell script in the cloud, without full control of the machine it is running on.  I need the mo74 (ibm mq powershell library).  Now, by default the two installation methods are from a fresh PS install or installing via dotnet, which I obviously can't use / won't be installed.  There is a method to include your own PS modules, but it seems the mo74 is a very odd module that isn't a "real" powershell module and just a hacky wrapper.  The library installs 3 dlls.

`WebSphereMQ.dll` `pshamqmdnet.dll` and `pshamqmdxcs.dll`

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\mo74_v2.0.1\mo74_v2.0.1_x86_x64\manual\MQLibrary\WebSphereMQ.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\mo74_v2.0.1\mo74_v2.0.1_x86_x64\manual\MQLibrary\pshamqmdnet.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\mo74_v2.0.1\mo74_v2.0.1_x86_x64\manual\MQLibrary\pshamqmdxcs.dll"
```

I have attempted to do this, however on the `WebSphereMQ.dll` load, I get this error:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path
"C:\Users\user\Downloads\mo74_v2.0.1\mo74_v2.0.1_x86_x64\manua ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoad
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

The other 2 dlls load fine.  But I believe the `WebSphereMQ.dll` is the main library portion.  I also attempted to use refelction.

Any ideas on how to load this library?

Comment: MO74 requires the MQ client to be installed.

Comment: @JoshMc  Hmm, so accessing IBM-MQ would not be possible on a cloud computing powershell script where you don't have full access to the machine it is running on?

Comment: I was able to install and use MO74 on a PC without any type of MQ installed, a fresh virtual machine.

Comment: Everything I read says it depends on the MQ install (either server or client).  You say you could install it but did you actually use it with out any type of MQ install?

Comment: I installed it, and accessed the methods(for example `Start-WMQChannel` and it started a dialog to do that and I just quit), but you're right, I never actually made a call to a working server (only working ibm mq server I have credentials too requires a whitelisted IP which I don't have). I just find it very odd I can get this far, but when I try to execute a functioning method it would fail, I believe you, I just find it very odd.  Any chance you could link me to the readings that stated you need mq client or server? @JoshMc

Comment: I do find it strange myself that the MO74 download page and the MO74.pdf file do not mention that the MQ install is a dependency, but based on what I know about MQ as a MQ admin it makes sense.  IBM has released wrappers like this for other things like Go and nodejs and this is always a requirement.  Same for similar things created outside of IBM like pymqi and the perl MQ modual.  The discussion thread that mentioned it needed the dlls installed with MQ is http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=66746&sid=8fe411d3a1e638196ecee93941c00b40.

Comment: Note that you could go through and try to connect to a queue manager with bad hostname and port and you should get an error indicating such, but you will probably get an error about missing dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked the `LoaderExceptions` like the error suggests? Reproduce the error and have a look at `$Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions`